# Disable Nautilus password saving

Tags: nautilus, password

It's possible to disable the Nautilus's password saving capability when I connect to windows share? I want to achieve that every time the user opens a password protected windows share, he/she should enter his/her username and password. Now there are three options when I open a windows share in Nautilus. The password could be remembered forever, it could be remembered until the user logs out, or it could be forgotten by Nautilus when it's closed. And the user could chose one of these options. I want to disable these options so every time when somebody wants to access a shared folder, a valid username and password is required.